# Request for all entries in a Contentful space not finding entries by field name

Tags: python-3.x, contentful, contentful-api

I have a content model: `Category`, with two entries for the Category content.

which I am retrieving with this function:

```
def categories(request):
    contentful_client = contentful.Client(CONTENTFUL_SPACE_ID,
                                      CONTENTFUL_TOKEN_ID)

    category_entries = contentful_client.entries()

    for entry in category_entries:
        print(getattr(entry, 'categoryName', 'not found'))

    for entry in category_entries:
        print(entry)

    count = len(category_entries)
    return HttpResponse('There are %d categories' % count)
```

The output for this is:

```
 not found
 not found
 <Entry[category] id='7hzRlNZw9cvKeYBQPGRV9a'>
 <Entry[category] id='2ZV3W30qLSosL5PPmKEoD5'>
```

I'm wondering why the attribute `categoryName` not being recognized since the entry has two attributes `categoryName` and `categoryBlob`

The [documentation](https://www.contentful.com/developers/docs/python/tutorials/getting-started-with-contentful-and-python/) I'm following does it in the same way:

```
for entry in entries:
    print(getattr(entry, 'product_name', 'Not a product'))


Not a product
Not a product
Whisk Beater
Hudson Wall Cup
Not a product
Not a product
Not a product
Not a product
SoSo Wall Clock
Not a product
Not a product
Not a product
Playsam Streamliner Classic Car, Espresso
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, `getattr` doesn't allow camelcase arguments.

I changed:

`print(getattr(entry, 'categoryName', 'not found'))`

to:

`print(getattr(entry, 'category_name', 'not found'))`

even though the name of the attribute is `categoryName` and it worked.